# Pushing a vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a file that goes like this:

```
98
287 2352
987 4313 3253
235 34325 432 123
```

Basically I want to reproduce this file. I am trying to import a line at a time, extract the numbers, and push them into vectors. Each vector is pushed into a larger vector.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sum = 0, one = 0, two = 1;
    std::string line, number;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> bigvec;
    auto k = vec.begin();
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    while(in >> line) {
        std::istringstream is(line);
        while(is >> number) {
            vec.push_back(stoi(number));
        }
        bigvec.push_back(vec);
        while(!vec.empty()) {
            vec.pop_back();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code though, when I print the result, seems to put each number in it's own vector instead of reproducing the file.

So my output is

```
98
287
2352
etc.
```

It seems that the line

```
while(is >> number) {
    vec.push_back(stoi(number));
}
```

pushes one number and then exits the loop.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `while(!vec.empty()) { vec.pop_back(); }` Eww! `vec.clear();` will do just that.

Comment: `std::string number;` Eww! `int number; while(is >> number) {vec.push_back(number);}` will do just fine.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing :)

Comment: [voilà](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7a896c419cdb0b6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while(in >> line)` reads next **word** from the input. Use `getline(in, line)` if you want to read a whole **line**.

There are multiple optimizations that you can add to your code. For instance instead of using `stoi` on the string you've read you can read an integer from the input stream. Also instead of popping the vector's elements one by one you can simply call `clear`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem lies here:

```
while(in >> line)
```

C++ by defult reads until it encounters interval or new line. In your case it encounters interval before new line. If you want to take the whole line take:

```
getline(cin, line);
```